# How to play video with Kotlinin Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-videoview

Im trying to play a mp4 file from a VideoView in one of my activities. I've come acrross a few tutorials online and have so far gotten the below code. I find that when I enter the activity the screen will stay black instead of starting the video. The video is named surfer.mp4 in my raw folder

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video)


        val filePlace = "android.resource://"+ packageName + "/raw/"+R.raw.surfer


        val videoView = findViewById<View>(R.id.videoView) as VideoView

        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(filePlace))

        videoView.setMediaController(MediaController(this))

        setContentView(videoView)
        videoView.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `packageName` set to?

Comment: @RyanM from the koitlin class

package com.example.myapplication